What do we do with answers consisting of dead links?
Today, I answered a question about altcoin price charts from 2011. Most of the original answers were outdated, of course. Four answers contained broken links, and given the nature of the question, the links were the only relevant information.
I was going to comment 'deceased link' four times (because 'dead link' is too short), but is that useful? Should a moderator delete outdated answers?


Should a moderator delete outdated answers?

Yep. Done.
